# how to take data in txt files such as mysql?

Tags: php, database, fopen

(my first language is no english)
i want to take data in txt files line by line.

Example:(This is my txt files)

```
exampleline1
exampleline2
exampleline3
exampleline4
```

(1)i want to select all lines and print. How to?

(2)For example i want to print line 4. How to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$lines = file("file.txt");
foreach($lines as $line){
  echo $line."<br>";
}
```

to print line 4

```
echo $lines[3];
```

Comment: is this faster than mysql? what is the shortcomings for mysql?

Comment: @MalcolmX It really depends on what exactly are you trying to do and how big is the file. Using mysql gives you the ability to narrow down your record set based on your `WHERE` clause, sort the data and do some many other wonderful things but if you don't need all that you have just a few lines of data to show, I think this will hold.

Comment: @MalcolmX i am not entirely sure what you mean but "where" can be implemented while dealing with text files, however it might not be as flexible or speedy as what MySQL provides

Answer (score 1):

use (But be careful not to waste your memory):
[file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
[fgets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)
[file](http://www.php.net/file)

Answer (score 1):

use function [file();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) which returns array (line by line)